# ASP.NET 5 web app not running in debug mode in IIS Express

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, iis-express, .net-4.6

Completely following this [Tutorial](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html) including the prerequisites described there, I created the web app ContosoBooks using `VS2015` Professional on `Windows 7`. The app compiles successfully but when I run the app in debug mode using F5 in Visual Studio, it waits for a long time and finally gives me this error:
[image]
The project properties are set to default as follows:
[image]
[image]

The windows event log shows the following message: `The directory specified for caching compressed content C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\iisexpress\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\Clr4IntegratedAppPool is invalid.  Static compression is being disabled`

The project.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-ContosoBooks-1954a805-4685-4556-982f-138333528f36",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you hitting **localhost:50711** when your project settings indicate that the website is hosted at **localhost:49723**?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I've reloaded the image1 that shows localhost:49723. The old image was from when first time I had created this project. After I got this error, I deleted the project and recreated it, hence the port number was changed from 50711 to 49723. The error is still exactly the same.

Comment: Is this on your development machine? You could try to enable the full IIS from Windows' Add or Remove Features

Comment: @cFrozenDeath It's our local machine and I verified using [this MSDN article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753658(v=ws.10).aspx) that the trust level is set to Full.

Comment: I didn't mean the trust level, I meant IIS version. What I'm saying you should do is install the full (not express) version of IIS, and change the project to use that.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath How do I use IIS in VS2015. There does not seem to be an easy way of doing it in VS2015. In earlier versions I would use the project settings to create virtual directory and point that to the project's main directory. But I don't see that option in VS2015.

Comment: See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178108.aspx

Comment: @cFrozenDeath The link you sent will not work for VS2015. As I mentioned in my previous comments the project settings window in VS2015 (shown in image 2 of my original post) does not have the options for choosing full IIS.

Comment: have you tried starting the app from the commandline? It may give you some additional info if there is an exception during initialization. Just run `dnx web` in your project directory.

Comment: @qbik Per your suggestion I tried `dnx web` and got the following output:  <br/>`C:\DotNet2015\MVC\ASP5TestApp\src\ASP5TestApp>dnx web  <br/>
Hosting environment: Production  <br/>
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000  <br/>
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commenting out `app.UseBrowserLink()` in the startup.cs allowed me to use Bitdefender Endpoint Security and ASP.Net 5.

I found this work around on the asp.net github page.

https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/309

Comment: Thank you for providing a workaround. I specially appreciate you pointing out to the github link related to this issue. I've BitDefender installed and this workaround resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same issue, and I've found a reason for it: Bitdefender AV. Completely uninstalling Bitdefender (download an uninstaller from their site) resolved the problem for me. Why Bitdefender interferes with running an ASP.NET 5 application, I cannot understand. I've registered a support ticket with Bitdefender, but haven't received any reply yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Bitdefender and Visual Studio 2015 can be resolved by simply uninstalling and installing of Bitdefender. Probably the issue was removed from the new distributions of the software.

Comment: sadly, this has not been my experience